# Proving non-existence of real roots

Tags: roots, algebraic-equations

Prove that for any real numbers $a_{85}, a_{84}, a_{83},\dots ,a_3$ the equation $a_{85}x^{85}+ a_{84}x^{84}+ a_{83}x^{83}+\dots +a_3x^3+3x^2+2x+1=0$ has no real roots. (This problem is stated in ALGEBRA book by Arihant Publication).

My doubt is that this is an odd degree equation when $a_{85}\neq 0$ then it will have at least one real root.

Answer (score 1):

And you are right. Unless $a_{85}=0$, that equation *must* have a real root.

Comment: Moreover, even if $a_{85}=0$, it's easy to find $a_{3}, \ldots, a_{84}$ for which it has a real root.  Just make the left side negative at, say, $x=1$.

Comment: Thanks Robert and Carlos. I was just thinking whether I am missing something out there. The text in book is perhaps incorrectly typed.